# how to show pictures and resource in sub directory with htaccess?

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

I have a laravel project in a subdirectory.
The project in root works correctly.
but in subdirectory not shows some pictures and resources.

I change `<base href= "/" />` to `<base href= "/sub" />`

but most of the pictures saved like this: `/apple-touch-icon.png` so url is:

```
http://example.com/apple-touch-icon.png
```

but I want

```
http://example.com/sub/apple-touch-icon.png
```

can I manage it via htaccess without change url of pics?

this is the htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

    ErrorDocument 403 /404

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,7}\s/(.*)index\.php\sHTTP.*$
    RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

add this line

```sh
#all request to sub dir
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sub/$1 [L]
```

here `sub` is folder you can change it